# Set ROUND() function for entire mysql query

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to apply ROUND function for entire select statement in MYSQL instead of using it for every column?

I want to avoid repeating ROUND

```
SELECT
  ROUND(col_1,2),
  ROUND(col_2, 2),
  ROUND(col_3,2)
FROM
  TABLE_NAME
```

Could not find anything related in documentation.

Comment: No.  You need it for every field.  How would it know how many digits you want?

Comment: Why is it important to you? is the column number a lot, so the query writing takes time, or are the columns dynamic?

Comment: @TimRoberts I mean using Round with known parameter of digits. In this case 2.

Comment: @s.abbaasi To avoid repitition in code.

Comment: Your example doesn't have the same number of digits in each case, but regardless of that, the answer is no.  SQL is explicit.  Most SQL statements are generated by program code anyway, so this is not a typing burden.

Comment: Thanks @TimRoberts, that makes sense. Apologies, I edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to avoid repetition in code, here is a trick for 100 columns:

```
SET @q = 'SELECT ';
SET @i = 0;
WHILE @i < 100 DO
   SET @q = CONCAT(@q, 'ROUND(col_',@i,',2), ');
   SET @i = @i + 1;
END WHILE;
SET @q = CONCAT(SubStr(@q, 1, LENGTH(@q) - 2),' FROM TABLE_NAME');    
PREPARE stmt FROM @q;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

You need to put it on a procedure and then call it.